# Fedora 15 doesn't automatically launch the browser when server starts up?

Tags: linux, fedora, webserver, browser

When I start up the ring jetty server, Fedora 15 doesn't launch the browser as it does in Fedora 14. Instead, it launches a new window in which I couldn't see the address bar and other stuff. Furthermore, Fedora 15 has a browser named Konqueror (instead of Firefox) as default, and I installed Firefox also. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to force Fedora to start Firefox, edit the startup settings by adding Firefox as a startup application by running the command `gnome-session-properties` on the terminal or run-query.